# Where is the std equivalent of boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast in C++11?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, shared-ptr

`boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast` and the other `boost::shared_ptr` functions reside in `<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`

I recently enabled support for C++11 in GCC with `-std=c++0x`. In order to avoid confusion, I moved from `boost::shared_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` which resides in `#include <memory>`.

However it appears that `shared_polymorphic_downcast` is not part of the `std` namespace and is not included with `#include <memory>`.

Do you know where it is? Did I miss the deprecation memo ;-)

Comment: Can't deprecate a feature that never was in.

Comment: Lol, yes yes, I was joking. I often mistakenly blur the line between popular Boost features and the STL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You either need `std::static_pointer_cast` or `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, depending on whether you want `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` behavior.

Recent versions of Boost's Smart Pointers library include these functions for `boost::shared_ptr` too.

Comment: Right on.  See here for some discussion: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/03/10589.php